# How would you express the idiom, "It is what it is"?

Tags: idiom

In English, we have the idiom:

> It is what it is.

It usually describes a thing or situation with immutable negative qualities, so you have no choice but to accept them.

How would one express this in Latin? I'm curious if there's a way to preserve the literal meaning of the English phrase in a way that could express the idiomatic meaning through context.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but for some cases *quod periit, periit* might be nice choice.

Comment: Not the same either, but *dura lex, sed lex* comes to mind. “The law is hard/rough, but it is the law.”